# Update Manager Not working due to missing CD-ROM

Tags: 11.10, kernel, updates, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

> W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 *Oneiric Ocelot* - Release i386 (20111012)/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
>   ,
>
> W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 *Oneiric Ocelot* - Release i386 (20111012)/dists/oneiric/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
>   ,
>
> E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

---

This happens when i hit the check button? and the updates were working before.

Comment: possible duplicate -- http://askubuntu.com/q/125111/63478 -- can we merge answers please?