# Can't upgrade 12.04 from 11.04

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

I have an 11.04 machine, and I'd like to upgrade to 12.04.  I'm using the Update Manager to do so.  It gets to the "Setting new software channels" step when  I get this error:

[image: Error during update]

The complete description is:

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What do I do?

Comment: before you carry on! - please confirm that you have first upgraded to 11.10 before upgrading to 12.04...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
Run in terminal:

`gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

there are the top few lines referencing the CD, add a hash character at the start to make them comments, save the new file and close gedit. A hash character is a '#'

Now try updating
Is it smooth?

Comment: That was the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this from a Terminal:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help you
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes
and this will help you
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OneiricUpgrades

You cant directly upgrade from ubuntu 11.04(Oneiric Ocelot) to Ubuntu 12.04(Precise Pangolin). First you will have to upgrade to 11.10 then only you can do the upgrade.
If you want to upgrade, then follow the instruction in those urls.
Always read release notes before upgrading.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen you can only update to 12.04 from 10.04 which is the previous LTS or from 11.10 which is the previous Ubuntu version.

You would have to update from 11.04 to 11.10 and then to 12.04 or download/install the CD/DVD/USB of 12.04.