# What are "Failed to fetch cdrom" errors in Update Manager and how do I fix them?

Tags: 10.04, apt, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

Whenever I run update-manager, I am getting the following error:

```
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release amd64 (20110211.1)/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release amd64 (20110211.1)/dists/lucid/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/qwibber-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
```

- How can I get rid of these errors?
- What is this error trying to tell me?

Comment: possible duplicate --- http://askubuntu.com/q/125111/63478 --can we merge answers please?