# How to fix "Failed to fetch" repository errors?

Tags: 12.04, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

This is basically what I'm getting after trying to add repositories so that I can add lenses.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  
Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/jsevi83/unity/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
```

There's more that I'm guessing aren't too dubious.  Very similar to the others.  Again, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The source url is invalid. It dowsn't contain any files. That's why it is failing.

Follow this URL - http://ppa.launchpad.net/jsevi83/unity/ubuntu/dists/

You can see there are no files.

Probably you are following some outdated instruction to install some specific lenses.