# Cannot get Ubuntu 12.04 to update

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

I have been using Ubuntu for about 6 months now without any problems until I ran the update manager yesterday and kept getting this message:

```
 Failed to download repository information Check your Internet connection
```

Then in the more details box it reported:

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120425)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried using the terminal commands given but have had no luck.

Answer (score 3):

The update manager is looking for packages on the Ubuntu CD/DVD. If it is not inserted you get that error. You can disable the CD as package source. Open the software center, go to `Edit/Software Sources...` and disable the CD on the first tab.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Since you seem to be new around here: Please mark my answer as solution. This way your question is marked as solved and others that might stumble upon it later can see that this was the solution (makes especially sense if there is more than one answer). Besides that I would get some reputation points ;-)

Comment: For some reason, I don't have that option. Any ideas as to why?