# How can I avoid "please insert CD/DVD" error when updating Ubuntu?

Tags: apt

I can't update 12.04 LTS. The Update Manager shows this:

```
CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)' is required
Please insert the above CD/DVD into the drive '/media/cdrom/' to install software packages from it.
```

The image I downloaded and burned to CD is from http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/
the PC (Intel x86) desktop CD version. I burned many CDs but the result is the same.

Comment: Instead of burning multiple images Ubuntu has a nice check feature for it's disks. You simply wait until you see the purple screen (with what looks like a man in a circle) on CD boot and then press "ESC" before you see the Ubuntu splash logo. There should be an option to check disk image. Also, try going to the Ubuntu Software Center, edit menu and software sources. On the other software tab what is selected?

Comment: CDs aren't used for regular updates.  They download via the internet.  Also, AFAIK, there's only one 12.04 LTS, although the title of your question confusingly suggests you are updating 12.04 to 12.04, so could you clarify what you are trying to do?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/177538/cannot-get-ubuntu-12-04-to-update/)

Comment: There are 3 updates in Update manager that require this:
CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin - Release i386 (20120423)' is required

"Please insert the above CD/DVD into the drive '/media/cdrom/' to install software packages from it."

2 Recommended updates:
Daemon which notifies about package updates
update-notifier (Size:57 kB)
Files shared between update-notifier and other packages

Comment: There are 3 updates in Update manager that require this:
CD/DVD 'Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin - Release i386 (20120423)' is required

"Please insert the above CD/DVD into the drive '/media/cdrom/' to install software packages from it."

2 Recommended updates:
Daemon which notifies about package updates
update-notifier (Size:57 kB)
Files shared between update-notifier and other packages

1 Distribution updates
Apply a diff file to an original
pach (New Install)(Size:87 kB)

I know that my ubuntu downloads any new updates and I was suprised when this started to show up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

Answer (score 13):

Go to *Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources* and make following changes:
Uncheck the Cdrom option in *Ubuntu Software*.Also make sure that you have marked all the other options.
[image: Software Sources]

Now go to *Other Software* and uncheck the Cdrom options.
[image: Software Sources]

Now try running `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Allright!! 
I did all that you told me and it worked!
Thank you for all youre help!

Comment: This was helpful. I was just trying to install ubuntu tweak when i got this message. Why are these options enabled by default?

Answer (score -4):

Try opening your terminal and typing in `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: That doesn't actually upgrade any packages; it just updates information about what packages are available, in what versions, and from where. After running `sudo apt-get update`, to actually upgrade packages to their latest available versions (i.e., to "update the system"), you must run `sudo apt-get upgrade` and/or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. See [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) for details.

Comment: This doesn't help as it is looking for the source /cdrom/

Comment: Yes, but if there is no update information on the system, the system automatically falls back to the CD. It's common on new installs. Since the system and CD are 12.04, I'd imagine the user wishes to upgrade past 12.04. Which means, they need new update information.