# keeps asking for the CD how do I force it to stop asking for the CD

Tags: 12.04

I have installed 12.04 and am attempting to update the wireless drivers (I have a Dell Insiron 6400), but it keeps asking for an installation CD that I do not have. How do I force it to stop asking for the CD and go to the network?
The commands I am running are:

```
~$ sudo apt-get update
~$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
~$ sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
~$ sudo reboot
```

It asks for the Cd at step 2

Comment: See my answer for a very similar question:http://askubuntu.com/questions/178437/i-cant-update-12-04-lts/178442#178442

Answer (score 1):

You can `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and comment out the CD-ROM lines near the top of the file by placing a `#` symbol as the first character. Or you can launch the software center and edit > software sources and uncheck the cdrom as an option.