# apt-get asks me to insert CD, why?

Tags: apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can’t update 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178437/i-cant-update-12-04-lts)

I tried to install several package before and it happened before, actually Iþm getting this for

```
sudo apt-get install libvte-dev
```

and this is the tail...

```
0 upgraded, 56 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 10.9 MB/14.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 62.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main zlib1g-dev amd64 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3ubuntu4 [165 kB]
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

I'm online. Where is the problem?

Note: I installed ubuntu from USB stick - I have no CD

Answer (score 22):

If you have an internet connection, you can safely comment out the line starting with `deb cdrom: ....` in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`. You can edit this file with the command:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and simply prepend this line with the `#`-sign so that it looks something like this:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)]/ quantal main restricted
```

Save the file and don't forget to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: p.s. since you're removing the 'main' repository, you need to add to sources the http based one!!   https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/  <<-- tool that gives you the repo info