# How to install alien in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, alien

While running `sudo apt-get install alien`, there is an error: `Unable lock administrator directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that some other package or package update is already downloading, and it hasn't finished downloading yet, so the `/var/lib/dpkg/` directory is locked until it finishes. Try to install alien again in a couple of hours.

Comment: I'm trying this few days...same error. If there any command to stop back end download or updates....

Comment: Now i'm getting error, but 13.04 dvd inside cd rom " Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
"

Comment: Something like that should be asked as a separate question instead of hiding it inside a thread. Including all the details in your question will improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

[karel's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/310449/16913) should be correct in nearly every case... **however**, there are some cases where dpkg forgets to clean its lock after its done (it happened to me a couple of times), so then you have to remove it:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

But don't remove it unless you are *certain* dpkg isn't running:

```
ps -eo command | grep dpkg | grep -v 'grep' # If there is output, then it means
                                            # dpkg is running
```

Comment: Now i'm getting error, but 13.04 dvd inside cd rom " Media change: please insert the disc labeled 'Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail - Release amd64 (20130424)' in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter " – Zafran 41 secs ago edit

Comment: @Zafran Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/236288/apt-get-asks-me-to-insert-cd-why

Comment: Now i'm getting error, but 13.04 dvd inside cd rom " Media change: please insert the disc labeled 'Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail - Release amd64 (20130424)' in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter "

Comment: @Zafran, could you pastebin /etc/apt/sources.list, and then link it here?