# When I try to install my kernel headers I get "please insert the disc labeled 'Ubuntu'"

Tags: apt, software-installation, vmware

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to Install VMware Workstation 10.0.2.bundle. I followed the description on (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player).

While trying to install the Linux headers, I got this error message:

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled 'Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140417)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

I inserted the USB stick which I installed my Ubuntu from and I am still getting the error message.

I really need to install VMware workstation.

Comment: Did you originally install without an Internet connection? Do you have internet connectivity? It is probably easier, if you have a broadband Internet connection, to do all your software installs and updates via the Internet repositories.
Let me go find the specifics and how to enabled network repos, and I will post another comment with some suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid "please insert CD/DVD" error when updating Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178437/how-can-i-avoid-please-insert-cd-dvd-error-when-updating-ubuntu)

Answer (score 7):

The issue is fairly simple, you have the CDROM entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Just remove/comment out the line, and you will be fine:

```
sudo sed -i '/cdrom/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dearie. I did Just and i was able to clear that error now am stuck after running the " gksudo bash ./Downloads/VMware-Player-3.1.4-385536.i386.bundle " I get this window "Enter your password to perform Administrative task. This application 'bash'./Downloads/WMware 10.0.2.bundle" lets your modify essential parts of your system.

Comment: i entered my password and it just takes me to terminal and doing nothing. what do i do please?

Comment: @user276911 `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: dear all, thanks for your responses so far. i did what Braiam said, got and install the updates but after entering the password, it still did not start the installer file. what do i do next.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about now?

Comment: dearie? Anyway, you probably need a follow-up question.

Comment: WOoooooowwww, i cant believe a space in between the VMware player name .bundle caused me the problem. 

I simply renamed the file VMWare 10.0.2.bundle by removing all the spaces making it VMWare10.0.2.bundle and it installed correctly following the help from this ubuntu link.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player