# I can't install b43-fwcutter

Tags: 14.04, wireless, broadcom, b43

I have to install b43-fwcutter to my Ubuntu 14.04 for wireless. When I do

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

it says:

```
media change: please insert the disc labeled
'Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press enter
```

but I have no CD. I installed Ubuntu using my USB Flash Memory. I tried to plug USB back but it didn't help.

So how can I install b43-fwcutter to my Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you enable a cd/your installation media as software source in your system configuration?

Comment: Yes I did enabled. So I disabled and removed from sources.list and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Both firmware-b43-installer and b43-fwcutter can be installed from either Synaptic Package manager or (I think) Ubuntu software center. But you need to begin with finding out what installers/ firmware are really appropriate for your driver. I have an answer here. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2272677 It refers to other answers on the subject.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid "please insert CD/DVD" error when updating Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178437/how-can-i-avoid-please-insert-cd-dvd-error-when-updating-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Instead, I suggest:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: It didn't work so I use the command `sudo sed -i '/cdrom/d' /etc/apt/sources.list` and it worked.

Comment: @emreaydin149 Do put your solution in its own answer and mark it as accepted.