# Broken apt sources list?

Tags: apt, package-management, live-usb, 21.04

I am trying to do boot-repair using try Ubuntu from live disc. I need to do apt commands, however I keep getting:

```
Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Ubuntu 21.04 _Hirsute Hippo_ - Release amd64 (20210420)'
in the drive '/cdrom/' and press [Enter]
```

I have seen a solution about removing cdrom entries from `/etc/apt/sources.list`, so I did. Now my lists are only 4 active entries, none is cdrom:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-hirsute.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ hirsute main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-hirsute.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/ hirsute main
```

I have also checked UI to make sure that option to use CD is NOT selected
and I have done `sudo apt-get update` multiple times, however I keep getting the same error. Do you know how to remove this error message? Or is it impossible to get rid of on live version?

The command I am trying to run is:

```
sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sdb5" apt-get purge --allow-remove-essential -y grub*-common shim-signed
```

Comment: Why would you run that command? You're going to remove many dependencies along with those packages. If you are going to purge and reinstall a package, you can use dpkg to purge instead and then use apt to reinstall. This way, it will not remove dependencies.

Comment: You're confused. Editing sources.list on your Ubuntu Live DVD does no good. What does boot-repair have to do with running (dangerous) cli commands? What makes you want to run those commands anyway?

Comment: I have a problem with dual booting. I am trying to fix it using boot-repair. That's why it needs to remove grub from live cd and then install it again. There was a step where I should execute commands to remove grub manually.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I avoid "please insert CD/DVD" error when updating Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178437/how-can-i-avoid-please-insert-cd-dvd-error-when-updating-ubuntu)

Comment: @N0rbert No, I have tried unticking this option in UI and removing entry from `sources.list` (after which I did `apt update`), both did not work