# Why is Update Manager giving "Failed to fetch CD-ROM..." errors?

Tags: updates, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

When I check for updates, I get this the message:

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012)/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111012)/dists/oneiric/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please suggest what I should do?