# trouble in updating my xubuntu 12.04.02

Tags: updates, xubuntu, update-manager

When I try tp update my xubuntu in "Update Manager" I get this error:

```
Failed to download repository information
```

When I try to update through terminal I get this:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Xubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What should I do? It hasn't been updated for 10 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the following link for an Answer to your Question.

[Why is Update Manager giving "Failed to fetch CD-ROM..." errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185720/why-is-update-manager-giving-failed-to-fetch-cd-rom-errors)

Have Fun !

Comment: Thanks!
The problem was that the "CD-ROM" option was checked in the "other software". Now it's ok :)