# Problem in apt-get update - Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

How to resolve the following error message?

#### Error Message:

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs, 
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs,           
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs, 
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release amd64 (20120823.1)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: First of all how are you updating? Are you using a live cd and trying apt-get update?

Answer (score 0):

open update manager
go to settings -> ubuntu software and unchek your CDROM
then go to other software and uncheck all CDROMs