# How di I fix this Synaptic manager error

Tags: synaptic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

Synaptic manager is giving me the following error:

```bash
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.04 _Natty Narwhal_ - Release i386 
  (20110427.1)/kubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to 
  make this CD-ROM recognised by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.04 _Natty Narwhal_ - Release i386 
  (20110427.1)/kubuntu/dists/natty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-      
  cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognised by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.04 _Natty Narwhal_ - Release i386 
  (20110427.1)/xubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to
  make this CD-ROM recognised by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 11.04 _Natty Narwhal_ - Release i386 
  (20110427.1)/xubuntu/dists/natty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognised by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert your Ubuntu cdrom into the drive before you refresh the sources.  Otherwise, and more likely what you want, uncheck the cdrom from your list of Software Sources.

Comment: hi thanks for reply i unchecked cdrom tick ,im being told to check internet connection but i thought thats fine

Comment: also may i add im planning on installing the 12.4 but have been trying to resolve any outstanding issues first or is that unnessary

Comment: If you are upgrading from 11.04 to 12.10, then I would try to resolve outstanding issues.  Otherwise, backup important files and install 12.04 fresh.