# Issues installing qt5 & sdk for phone app

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I followed the instructions for downloading the qt5, but it failed.
I downloaded qt4 from package manager in 12.10.

I then tried to install sdk through terminal, but to no avail did it bring it up it gives the following errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal - Release amd64 (20121017.5)/dists/quantal/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Please give further instructions as to how I may get qt5 release and sdk, so that I may start to write programs for ubuntu phone.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, where on the following linked page: [Get the Ubuntu SDK preview](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/#step-get-toolkit) does qt5 get installed?  All I see is two new repositories and an install of the sdk and qml editor.

Comment: @TonyMartin, the `ubuntu-sdk` package installation on the second section takes care of that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, David, I suspected that might be the case.  However, when I try to set the qt viewer I cannot find it at /opt/qt5/bin.  Where should I look?  TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

Answer (score 1):

Actually your problem seems to be that you haven't configured a network package repository and instead have still the line from installation time in there, referring to your installation media. The easiest thing would be to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `grep -R 'deb cdrom' /etc/apt/` to see which of the files still refers to your installation media. Usually that would be `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Comment out the lines starting with `deb cdrom:` by prepending a `#` and then save.

After that make sure to also add some repositories. The normal method is to have contents such as these:

```
deb http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted
deb-src http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb-src http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal universe
deb http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe
deb-src http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb-src http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal multiverse
deb http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse
deb-src http:/<country-code>.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security multiverse
```

where `<country-code>` would be a two-letter country code as used in ccTLDs, such as `us` for USA, `de` for Germany etc. Basically you "local" package repository mirror for added speed. Those lines should already exist and you probably don't need to add or adjust them at all. Simply commenting out the lines starting with `deb cdrom` should be enough.

After editing make sure to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and watch out for further errors such as the ones from your question. Correct them until you see no errors and then install the packages you need or want.

Also make sure to consult `man sources.list` and [this documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine). And here's [an online tool to generate the entries for `sources.list`](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/).

There is also a graphical method to this, but I have no experience in this, as I prefer to edit `sources.list`. Also the graphical method differs depending on the Ubuntu flavor you're using, such as vanilla Ubuntu, Kubuntu ... etc.