# Can't install Ubuntu One after upgrade

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

I installed 10.04 today and immediately upgraded to 12.04 (Long story).  Tried to install Ubuntu One and got this warning:

QUOTE W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.4LTS_Lucid Lynx_-Release i386 (20120214.2)/dists/lucidmain/binary-i386/Packages Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT.apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
,W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.4LTS_Lucid Lynx_-Release i386 (201214.2)/dists/lucid/restricted/binary-i386/Packages Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
,E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead. UNQUOTE

I don't have a clue what this means nor do I know what to do.  Any help available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following Line:

```
Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.4LTS_Lucid Lynx_-Release i386 (20120214.2)/dists/lucidmain/binary-i386/Packages
```

Ubuntu tries to look for Software on a CD-ROM that does not exist.
Please remove the old CD-ROM Repository from your repositories.

To do so, go to **Settings -> Software & Updates (beyond System)**
Then, uncheck all CD-ROM repos.

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and retry reinstalling Ubuntu One.

If there is still no success, run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Look for every line, that has to do with CD-ROM. Comment it out by adding a # at the start of the line.

For instance:

```
...
#deb cdrom: ....
...
```

Then, to save the file, press **CTRL + O** and then commit the file name with **[ENTER]**.
Then, exit the command line editor with **CTRL + X**

After that, re-run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and retry installing Ubuntu One.