# Software Updater: Requires installation of untrusted packages

Tags: 14.04, updates, software-center, update-manager

I used `sudo apt-get update` command in terminal and resulted with below log,

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch in.archive.ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch in.archive.ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch archive.canonical/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release i386 (20140417)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release i386 (20140417)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W: Failed to fetch archive.ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:8080:
W: Failed to fetch in.archive.ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:8080:
W: Failed to fetch in.archive.ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:8080:
W: Failed to fetch in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:8080:
W: Failed to fetch archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:8080:
W: Failed to fetch extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 192.168.0.2:8080:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes, i am connected to internet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

Answer (score 0):

Either keep the Installation CD for your OS in the CDROM and then run `sudo apt-get update` or remove the CD as an option from the Software Repositories (sources).

Comment: I tried removing the source and executed the command but result seems to be the same.