# how to install skype in my ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

how to install skype on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS I have tried for `sudo apt-get install skype` but no use

Answer (score 1):

You can download *.deb file from skype website, navigate to file location, press F4 to open terminal window and type:

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

You may need to do

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

to install some dependencies

The last step is to install Pulse audio, because without it you won't be able to play/record sound with skype:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Happy skyping!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Software and Updates
2. In the Other Software tab check Canonical Partners
3. Close the dialogue box
   Ubuntu will reload the Software Cache
4. Go to terminal and run `sudo apt-get install skype`

Answer (score 0):

How to install skype is explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype
Start terminal by pressing `alt+f2`, write `gnome-terminal` and press enter then:

For enabling multiarch if you are using x64 version of Ubuntu

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Add the "partner" repository, since Skype isn't included in the main repositories(it is not open source):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

Install skype:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype pulseaudio:i386
```

Comment: in my terminal it shows my system is held with broken packages how do i correct it

Comment: Try to run sudo dpkg --configure -a.

Comment: Failed to fetch cdrom://[Ubuntu 12.04 _Precise_ - Build amd64 LIVE Binary 20130203-13:50]/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

it sjhows like this

Answer (score 0):

From [here.](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/to-install-skype-4-0-0-8-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/)

1. Add the PPA:

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise partner' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list"
   ```
2. Update your source list:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install skype:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install skype
   ```

Comment: when i use - sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise partner' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list" then it ask for password when i type password it get back top normal what should i do now

Comment: That means it worked!
Proceed to the next step.

Comment: when i use sudo apt-get update its working but al last it shows failed to fetch cd rom                                                                                                                                                     what should i do now

Comment: Can you please update your question with the error log?

Comment: what iam a new user i dont know how to use but i have the minimum idea to use it even though i tried ur idea its failed at last                                                         it shows that failed to fdetch the cd-rom

Comment: Does this help you? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom

Comment: no it shows something like this  failed to fetch cd-rom

Comment: what should i do now