# how to repair ubuntu

Tags: updates

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20120214.2)/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS _Lucid Lynx_ - Release i386 (20120214.2)/dists/lucid/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 0):

this describes how you can fix the CD-ROM issue using the graphical interface: [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom) .

this is the *command-line* version:

edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. you will (probably) find lines similar to

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.04 ...
```

in there. either add a `#` to the beginning of every such line:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 10.04 ...
```

or delete those lines altogether.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

should then work.

---

also note that lucid is no longer supported. you will not get any security updates anymore. i suggest you upgrade to a current version such as 14.04 trusty.

if you still want to use lucid you can. but you will have to change all the entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list` pointing to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ :

change the lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`  from

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ ...
```

to

```
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```