# while updating its throwing error like as follows :

Tags: updates

Error during update:

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 15.10 _Wily Werewolf_ - Release amd64 (20151021)/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 15.10 _Wily Werewolf_ - Release amd64 (20151021)/dists/wily/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 15.10 _Wily Werewolf_ - Release amd64 (20151021)/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 15.10 _Wily Werewolf_ - Release amd64 (20151021)/dists/wily/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: So fix it? "Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT" What more do you need? That line itself showed me http://askubuntu.com/a/120520/15811 on google.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the CD-ROM APT repository. This repo can be used if you have an Ubuntu Live CD to install software offline. You will probably want to disable this feature, otherwise some APT operations will throw you errors like these.

To do it, search for "software sources" in the Dash. Open Software Sources, go to System Admin tab and uncheck the option that says something like "CD-ROM for Ubuntu". Reload the sources and close. Now if you run `sudo apt-get update` or check for software upgrades with the update manager the problems should not appear anymore.