# I cannot update, install, upgrade or anything like before

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates

When I wish to update my system using `apt-get update` I get the following:

```
david@karens-PC:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for david: 
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty Release.gpg
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty Release
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty/main amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty/main i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Err cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty/restricted i386 Packages
  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty/main Translation-en_GB
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty/restricted Translation-en_GB
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2) trusty/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease                             
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                      
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg                                
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                    
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages                            
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease                         
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease                       
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_GB                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages      
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_GB                
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Sources             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Sources 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main i386 Packages  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources    
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_GB 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages 
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_GB                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_GB              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_GB              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_GB                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                   
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
david@karens-PC:~$
```

When I tried to update using `apt-get upgrade` I got the following:

```
david@karens-PC:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for david: 
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repo.steampowered.com_steam_dists_precise_steam_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: See [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](http://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

Comment: @steeldriver VTC as dupe

Comment: I have put the content from your "answer" into your question. Can you see the little grey bits of text underneath your question at the left hand side? One of them should say `share` and another should say `edit`. Click on `edit` to add content to your question.

Comment: However, don't use `edit` to change what you are asking in your question, or people will get cross and stop helping you. Rather, ask a new question if you have a new question!

Comment: There seem to be multiple issues here: 1) The bogus `cdrom://` entries and 2) the `Problem with MergeList` thing.

Answer (score 5):

I would say this looks ok. The missing CD-based package sources are simply ignored. The corresponding packages are also available from online sources.

Note that `apt-get update` only updates the local package index, i.e., it makes *metadata* about packages available locally. It doesn’t update your system.

To update your system, you should run the following *in addition*:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a terminal
2. Type in `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
3. Remove the lines containing the word `cdrom`
4. Exit with <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Update the package list with `sudo apt-get update`