# I get the error "Failed to download repository information. Check your Internet connection." How can I fix this?

Tags: 16.04, updates

I haven't been able to update my Ubuntu 16.04 machine for the past month because of this error. When I click to view the details, I get

```
W:Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gerardpuig-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:2 and
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gerardpuig-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:3, 
W:The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2) xenial Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., 
W:The repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/deepin-sc/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file., 
W:Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use., 
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
details., 
E:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs, 
E:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/deepin-sc/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources 404  Not Found, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Can you tell me what I possibly did wrong or what I can do to resovle this?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to offer several solutions:

1. To get rid of the cdrom error see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)
2. For the error:

   ```
   W:Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in
   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gerardpuig-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:2 and
   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gerardpuig-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list:3`
   ```

   - 1. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/gerardpuig-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list` and remove the duplicate entries for that repo there or just add `#` in front of one of the entry.

        ```
        sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gerardpuig-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
        ```
3. To fix this error `The repository http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/deepin-sc/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.,`

   - 1. remove the repo with:

        ```
        sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:noobslab/deepin-sc
        ```
4. After that run `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Thank you! I completed step 2, but for step 1, I get: "bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gerardpuig-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list: Permission denied." Any ideas? I also tried to put "sudo" and "su" in front of it. Same result.

Comment: Please do so from the `system settings` area as seen in those posts

Comment: try sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gerardpuig-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list