# "Media change: please insert the disk..." when I run "sudo apt-get install make" on Ubuntu on VirtualBox

Tags: apt, make

I have installed Ubuntu inside VirtualBox and generally I can `apt-get install` anything but when I run

```
sudo apt-get install make
```

I get this response:

```
Media change: please insert the disk labelled
'Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [enter]
```

---

I cannot do this as I'm in a VM and don't have a cdrom drive. I have successfully installed lots of packages using `apt-get` and I assume it gets them from the image I installed Ubuntu in the VM or online, so why does this problem occur for `make`?

Many thanks for any wisdom.

Comment: You can and probably should remove the installation "disk" from the software sources if the installation ISO is no longer available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125111/failed-to-download-repository-information-due-to-missing-cdrom)

Answer (score 1):

You should check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` – maybe the disk is still listed as a repository there.