# I'm trying to install wine and got an error

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, wine

At the WineHQ site I followed the first step to enable 32-bit architecture by entering this command `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, but an error appeared.

```
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
```

Comment: i'm using ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. the architecture is x86-64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds
/ubuntu/ focal main' 
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install -y wine32 wine64 wine-stable
```

Other suggested packages to install along with wine-stable are: *dosbox playonlinux winbind wine-binfmt winetricks*

Comment: still got some error

E: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200731)/dists/focal/main/binary-i386/Packages Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Please correct the CD-ROM error with [Failed to download repository information due to missing CDROM](https://askubuntu.com/q/125111/). Remove any lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` that include CD-ROM. Save the file and try once more.
Don't forget to run `sudo apt update` again after correcting the error.

Comment: CD-ROM error fixed. But now when i run `sudo apt install -y wine64 wine32 wine-stable` an error appeared 
E: Unable to locate package wine64
E: Unable to locate package wine32
E: Unable to locate package wine-stable

Comment: All the command is working fine, after that what should I do?

Comment: There's no need to do anything else. You're done if I'm not mistaken.